# Chrome extension icon missing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just added an extension named *Chrome History X*, but its supposed-to-have icon wouldn't appear in the tool bar next to the url box like any other icons did.

The author for the extension might intend to hide the icon from the tool bar, but my question is, how can I run the extension? It seems I can only delete the extension from *tools - > extensions* page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Store says on extension details tab:

> Overrides the default history page.

This means you need to access `chrome://history`. It puts an italicized button saying `Visualize this search`.

That's how that extension works.